# Call graph for handling TLB misses in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, tlb, mmu

I am trying to understand how the linux kernel handles TLB misses. Specifically, I know that the page table walk happens in `follow_page` in `mm/memory.c` but how is follow_page called when a TLB miss occurs. How is the return value (`struct page`) of follow_page passed back to the hardware? Can someone illustrate a call graph for the TLB miss handling from when a TLB Miss exception is raised by the hardware to when `follow_page` is called?

I searched for `follow_page` inside the kernel code http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.4.4/+search=follow_page but the results do not seem to help much.
To make things clear, lets say the hardware is x86_64.

Comment: I found out that for most x86 architectures, the hardware does the page walk when a TLB miss occurs. The software page walk code `follow_page` in `mm/memory.c` is not invoked during a TLB miss. So, as per my understanding, there is no call graph for handling TLB misses in linux kernel.

Comment: You should submit this comment as an answer.

Comment: @GargantuChet thanks. I have posted mine as the answer.

Comment: Great! It's more clear for anyone who happens to hit this page from search results. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 4):

I found out that for most x86 architectures, the hardware does the page walk when a TLB miss occurs. The software page walk code `follow_page` in `mm/memory.c` is not invoked during a TLB miss. So, as per my understanding, there is no call graph for handling TLB misses in linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed yourself, the MMU of intel processors since 80386 has hardware resolution for filling the translation lookaside buffers. That explains why the page table for this architecture have such a rigid structure. There are various places where walking down the page tables (as in `follow_page`) is required on this architecture, however, esp. in `handle_mm_fault`, although it is generally possible to expect a more specific case and drop most of the tests.